# Pros and cons of using a Http proxy v/s https proxy?

Tags: http, https, proxy

The JVM allows proxy properties http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort for specifying a HTTP proxy server and https.proxyHost and https.proxyPort for specifying a HTTPS proxy server .

I was wondering whether there are any advantages of using a HTTPS proxy server compared to a HTTP proxy server ?

Is accessing a https url  via a  HTTPS proxy less cumbersome than accesing it from a HTTP proxy ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

HTTP proxy gets a plain-text request and [in most but not all cases] sends a different HTTP request to the remote server, then returns information to the client.

HTTPS proxy is a relayer, which receives special HTTP request (CONNECT verb) and builds an opaque tunnel to the destination server (which is not necessarily even an HTTPS server). Then the client sends SSL/TLS request to the server and they continue with SSL handshake and then with HTTPS (if requested).

As you see, these are two completely different proxy types with different behavior and different design goals. HTTPS proxy can't cache anything as it doesn't see the request sent to the server. With HTTPS proxy you have a channel to the server and the client receives and validates server's certificate (and optionally vice versa). HTTP proxy, on the other hand, sees and has control over the request it received from the client.

While HTTPS request can be sent via HTTP proxy, this is almost never done because in this scenario the proxy will validate server's certificate, but the client will be able to receive and validate only proxy's certificate, and as name in the proxy's certificate will not match the address the socket connected to, in most cases an alert will be given and SSL handshake won't succeed (I am not going into details of how to try to address this).

Finally, as HTTP proxy can look into the request, this invalidates the idea of security provided by HTTPS channel, so using HTTP proxy for HTTPS requests is normally done only for debugging purposes (again we omit cases of paranoid company security policies which require monitoring of all HtTPS traffic of company employees).

Addition: also read my answer on the similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8612660/47961).

Comment: Excellent answer. So I was testing with a http proxy (burp proxy server). I was sending https requests over it. The proxy was able to connect to the https url and execute the url, but it was sending back the proxy certificate as you mentioned and my Java client(basic HTTPUrlConnection with the proxy specified in jvm settings) was unable to validate it.. So if I use a HTTPS proxy, this issue should be automatically resolved ?

Comment: @Zenil yes, as the communication will be direct between the client and the server (after the tunnel is built).

Comment: Doesn't the term HTTP Proxy incorporate potentially supporting SSL / HTTPS?  i.e. so-called HTTP Proxies can HTTPS and do nowadays..  Is HTTPS proxy really a term that is used much?

Comment: @barlop given that the two have different principle of work, even when they are merged in one software, they are still two different things.

Comment: would you agree though that when connecting to an https proxy you use http:// ? or is it not is it really just plain text and not specifically http?  youtube-dl  has the syntax  --proxy URL  e.g. I think `youtube-dl.exe --proxy "http://proxy.com:8080/" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzZJuEDQ1a0`

Comment: @barlop The protocol part of the URI identifies the protocol used to *connect to* the resource. In this case it means "connect to the proxy using HTTP and ask the proxy for access to HTTPS resource". Even with "HTTPS proxies" you use HTTP request with CONNECT verb, hence http:// protocol prefix. But this doesn't mean that you have an http proxy here.

Comment: You write "connect to the proxy using HTTP".  OK.. So, Prior to issuing the CONNECT verb, and when the connection itself is made, then In what way is it connecting to the HTTPS Proxy with HTTP? (and after the CONNECT verb it's all https).

Comment: @barlop at this point I should refer to the RFCs which you can read and know how it all works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76162/discussion-between-barlop-and-eugene-mayevski-eldos-corp).

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp: Great answer. However, I didn't quite get this: (In the 4th para) why would an HTTP proxy server present a certificate? And why would the certificate contain the proxy's address and not the server's address? Isn't a proxy supposed to just pass-on the response as-is?

Comment: @i08in I was talking about the case when you "inject" the HTTP proxy as the interceptor. The client expects end-to- end security,  which is impossible to achieve with an HTTP proxy. Of course if the client is aware of the proxy and accepts the fact that its secure connection ends in the middle,  then my concerns would not be applicable.

Comment: @barlop One can build a https proxy and make the client connect to a HTTP proxy server over TLS, nothing about MIIT would need to be involved. Follow the link of my answer to this question for more details.

Comment: @Rick  You write "One can build a https proxy and make the client connect to a HTTP proxy server over TLS,"   <----  You said build an https proxy, so it's connecting to an HTTPS PROXY. It has been a while but I think the TLS is done before it hits the proxy. So there is no connecting to an HTTP Proxy  in  this. It's connecting to An HTTPS Proxy, (the thing you said you 'build')

Answer (score 15):

There are no pros or cons.
And there are no "HTTPS proxy" server.

You can tell the protocol handlers which proxy server to use for different protocols. This can be done for `http`, `https`, `ftp` and `socks`. Not more and not less.

I can't tell you if you should use a different proxy for https connections or not. It depends.
I can only explain the difference of an http and https request to a proxy.

Since the *HTTP Proxy* (or web proxy) understands `HTTP` (hence the name), the client can just send the request to the proxy server instead of the actual destenation.
This does *not* work for `HTTPS`.
This is because the proxy can't make the TLS handshake, which happens at first.
Therefore the client must send a `CONNECT` request to the proxy.
The proxy establishes a TCP connection and just sends the packages forth and back without touching them.
So the TLS handshake happens between the client and destenation.
The HTTP proxy server does *not* see everything and does *not* validate destenation servers certificate whatsoever.

There can be some confusion with this whole http, https, proxy thing.
It is possible to connect *to* a HTTP proxy with https.
In this case, the communication between the client and the *proxy* is encrypted.

There are also so called `TLS terminating` or `interception` proxy servers like [Squid's SSL Peek and Splice](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslPeekAndSplice) or [burp](https://portswigger.net/burp/help/proxy_option), which *see everything*.
But this should not work out of the box, because the proxy uses own certificates which are not signed by trusted CAs.

#### References

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html
- https://parsiya.net/blog/2016-07-28-thick-client-proxying---part-6-how-https-proxies-work/
- http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/secure-web-proxy
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2817#section-5
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.6

Comment: There is "HTTPS proxy", if you mean connecting to a HTTP proxy server over TLS. See my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, "HTTPS proxy" has two distinct meanings:

1. A proxy that can forward HTTPS traffic to the destination. This proxy itself is using an HTTP protocol to set up the forwarding.

In case the browser is trying to connect to a website using HTTPS, the browser will send a CONNECT request to the proxy, and the proxy will set up a TCP connection with the website and mirror all TCP traffic sent on the connection from the browser to the proxy onto the connection between the proxy and the website, and similarly mirror the response TCP packet payload from the webite to the connection with the browser. Hypothetically, the same mechanism using CONNECT could be used with HTTP traffic, but practically speaking browsers don't do that. For HTTP traffic, they send the actual HTTP request to the proxy, including the full path in the HTTP command (as well as setting the `Host` header): https://stackoverflow.com/a/38259076/10026

So, by this definition, HTTPS Proxy is a proxy that understands the CONNECT directive and can support HTTPS traffic going between the browser and the website.

2. A proxy that uses HTTPS protocol to secure client communication.

In this mode (sometimes referred to as "Secure Proxy"), the browser uses the proxy's own certificate to perform TLS handshake with the proxy, and then sends either HTTP or HTTPS traffic, (including CONNECT requests), on that connection as per (1). So, the connection between the browser and the proxy is always protected with a TLS key derived using the proxy's certificate, regardless of whether the traffic itself is encrypted with a key negotiated between the browser and the website. If HTTPS traffic is proxied via a secure proxy, it is double-encrypted on the connection between the browser and the proxy.

For example, the [Proxy Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switcher/iejkjpdckomcjdhmkemlfdapjodcpgih?hl=en) Chrome plugin has two separate settings to control each of these funtionalities:

[image]

As of 2022, the option to use a secure proxy is not available in MacOS and Windows manual proxy configuration UI. But a secure proxy may be specified in a PAC file used in automatic proxy configuration using the [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_PAC_file#description) proxy directive. It is up to the consuming application to support the HTTPS directive; most major browsers, except Safari, and many desktop apps support it.

NOTE: Things get a bit more complicated because some proxies that proxy HTTPS traffic don't simply forward TCP packet payload, as described in (1), but act as Intercepting Proxies. Using a spoofed website certificate, they effectively perform a Man-in-the-Middle attack (well, it's not necessarily an attack because it's expected behavior). Whereas the browser thinks it's using the website's certificate to set up a TLS tunnel with a website, it's actually using a spoofed certificate to set up TLS tunnel with the proxy, and the proxy sets up the TLS tunnel with the website. Then proxy has visibility into the HTTPS requests/responses. But all of that is completely orthogonal to whether the proxy is acting as a secure proxy as per (2).

Answer (score 8):

If you mean **connecting to a HTTP proxy server over TLS** by saying **HTTPS proxy**, then

> I was wondering whether there are any advantages of using a HTTPS
>   proxy server compared to a HTTP proxy server ?

The advantage is that your client's connection to proxy server is encrypted. E.g. A firewall can't not see which host you use `CONNECT` method connect to.

> Is accessing a https url via a HTTPS proxy less cumbersome than
>   accesing it from a HTTP proxy ?

Everything is the same except that with HTTPS proxy, brower to proxy server connection is encrypted.

But you need to deploy a certificate on your proxy server, like how a https website does, and use a `pac` file to configure the brower to enable **Connecting to a proxy over SSL**.

For more details and a practical example, check my question and answer here [HTTPs proxy server only works in SwitchOmega](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56981993/https-proxy-server-only-works-in-switchomega)