# Java HttpClient - Post with file through Proxy

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I try calling an external website from my webapplication with a proxy. Furthermore and need to execute a POST Request at this external website.

I'm using: tomcat7, org.apache.httpcomponents 4.3.4, spring.

Following, without proxy, works and I get a response status '200';

```
    // uri = "https://punkte.eiv-fobi.de/upload/upload.do"
    private HttpStatus sendPost(URI uri, File file)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);

    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    builder.addPart(PART_NAME, fileBody);
    httpPost.setEntity(builder.build());

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    return HttpStatus.valueOf(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }
```

now I tried this adding the proxy:

```
    // uri = "https://punkte.eiv-fobi.de/upload/upload.do"
public HttpStatus sendPostWithProxy(URI uri, File file) throws Exception {
    try {
        // JVM Parameter: -Dhttps.proxyHost and -Dhttps.proxyPort
        String proxyHost = System.getProperty("https.proxyHost");
        String proxyPort = System.getProperty("https.proxyPort");

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        // CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost,
                Integer.valueOf(proxyPort), "https");

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file,
                ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        builder.addPart(PART_NAME, fileBody);
        httpPost.setEntity(builder.build());

        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy)
                .build();
        httpPost.setConfig(config);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        return HttpStatus.valueOf(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(
                "exception occurred.",
                e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

getting following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

What Do Im wrong? Alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few issues that could cause this:

- Are you sure your https proxy does not require authentication? In that case you would probably need to set the credentials in a context and execute the request using the context and the client.Check this example: http://www.the-swamp.info/blog/java-request-through-proxy/
- Since you are using an https proxy and requesting an https url (SSL/TLS endpoint security) you may have problems with certificate validation. Check this good explanation for https proxies: [Pros and cons of using a Http proxy v/s https proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440690/pros-and-cons-of-using-a-http-proxy-v-s-https-proxy/10442767#10442767)