# Docker: npm install behind proxy

Tags: proxy, docker, npm

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:argon

ENV http_proxy http://user:pass@proxy.company.priv:3128
ENV https_proxy https://user:pass@proxy.company.priv:3128

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

But I get this error, in **npm install** step:

> npm info it worked if it ends with ok npm info using npm@2.14.12 npm
>   info using node@v4.2.6 npm WARN package.json deployer-ui@1.0.0 No
>   description npm WARN package.json deployer-ui@1.0.0 No repository
>   field. npm WARN package.json deployer-ui@1.0.0 No README data npm info
>   preinstall deployer-ui@1.0.0 npm info attempt registry request try #1
>   at 7:09:23 AM npm http request GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser npm info attempt registry
>   request try #1 at 7:09:23 AM npm http request GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/express npm info retry will retry, error on
>   last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established,
>   cause=write EPROTO npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt:
>   Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO

I guess it is due to the proxy. I have also tried to put

```
RUN npm config set proxy http://user:pass@proxy.company.priv:3128
RUN npm config set https-proxy http://user:pass@proxy.company.priv:3128
```

but still getting the same error.

Moreover, in my file **/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf** I have this:

```
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://user:pass@proxy.company.priv:3128"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://user:pass@proxy.company.priv:3128"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First the `https_proxy` should use an **http** url, not an https url.

Second, you don't need to embed your proxy settings in your Dockfile: you can use [build time variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg)

> `docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://user:pass@proxy.company.priv:3128 --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:pass@proxy.company.priv:3128 .`

Finally, [proxy settings at the docker service level](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#http-proxy:43644c643e7f8892a9f8a45991d7cd50) allows the docker daemon to pull images from internet. It does not mean the unix command executed (`RUN` directive) by `docker build` would benefit from them. Hence the need to pass them as build-time environment variables.

Comment: I want to note that build variables can also be set in a compose file: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args

Comment: Why do all the https_proxy variables use http urls instead of https urls? I've always seen this but never understood why

Comment: @Goku No need for encryption at the proxy level: https://serverfault.com/a/817684/783 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47474561/6309

Comment: is it possible to configure docker to always use the http proxy while doing docker build? This would be useful if there are lots of  pre-built scripts or binaries doing docker build.

Comment: @Goku I don't think so, beside creating an alias.

Answer (score 6):

I also had the same issue and did not want to set any proxy information in my image as I did not want be dependant of my company environment.

My solution was to use  a cntlm running in gateway mode. To do so I put the flag `Gateway` set to `yes` the following allow rules in my cntlm configuration file:

```
 Gateway         yes
 # Allow local
 Allow           127.0.0.1
 # Allow docker subnetwork
 Allow           172.17.0.0/16
```

Then I was able to run my docker file by getting the *dokcer0* interface address (got with `ifconfig`command):

```
docker build -t my-image --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://172.17.0.1:3128 --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://172.17.0.1:3128 .
```

Same with `docker run`:

```
docker run --rm -e HTTP_PROXY=http://172.17.0.1:3128 --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://172.17.0.1:3128 my-image
```

However please note that since docker 17.07 you can simply [configure the docker client proxy](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client).

Hence your `~/.docker/config.json` will be like

```
{
  "proxies": {
      "default":{
          "httpProxy": "http://172.17.0.1:3128/",
          "httpsProxy": "http://172.17.0.1:3128/",
          "noProxy": "127.0.0.1,172.17.0.0/16,*.some.compagny.domain"
      }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue but your solution does not work for me. I have cntlm running successfull with Firefox, proxy setting to 127.0.0.1:3128. But no matter what I try as IP with docker it doesn't work. I'm using Windows 10. I have 10.0.75.0 as Subnet Address and for ipconfig /all I have 10.0.75.1. NPM will not install anything. Any idea? BTW: If I insert proxy information user:pw@proxy.de it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Adding this to Dockerfile worked for me:

```
RUN npm config set https-proxy http://user:password@proxy.company.priv:80
RUN npm config set proxy http://user:password@proxy.company.priv:80
```

Comment: I also had to add `RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` to force the connection to use HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/) adding the following to `~/.docker/config.json` helped me:

```js
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "httpsProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com"
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Just that you know, this package was written by myself)

You can use [docker-container-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docker-container-proxy), it allows configuration of a proxy for any docker container without editing any code.

Just run:

```
npx dockerproxy start --address company-proxy-address.com --port 8080
# Do anything else that needs a Proxy
```