# Should the address of http_proxy always be "http://"?

Tags: windows, proxy, http-proxy, squid

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue with `http_proxy` (Windows, HTTP Proxy), when the address starts with `https://something` it would fail.

I've setup my own Squid-Windows proxy just to test the use cases... it works fine when is `http` but failed when is `https` (in fact I've also tried the same thing with CCProxy too, same result)

Then I stumbled across the following 2 resources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_method
- [Pros and cons of using a Http proxy v/s https proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440690/pros-and-cons-of-using-a-http-proxy-v-s-https-proxy)

If I understands correctly, the HTTP Proxy's address should always be `http://` and not `https://`? Is that correct?