# Jetty ConnectHandler with Upstream Proxy

Tags: ssl, proxy, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am using Jetty's ConnectHandler to proxy SSL via CONNECT.

Now I'd like to configure the ConnectHandler to forward requests to another proxy which will handle the CONNECT for me.

Is there a way to configure the ConnectHandler to do this?
I checked the [ConnectHandler source code](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-proxy/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/ConnectHandler.java) but couldn't find a way to do this.

Comment: Post the current code that you have used also to your question

Comment: @TarunLalwani This is currently my code: https://github.com/testingbot/Testingbot-Tunnel/blob/java8/src/main/java/com/testingbot/tunnel/proxy/CustomConnectHandler.java

Here we receive a CONNECT request and handle it. But now I also want to be able to forward it to another proxy.

Comment: See if this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357585/creating-a-java-proxy-server-that-accepts-https